# Extension for visual studio 2015 to insert images in code

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'd like to be able to add images to my code in visual studio 2015.
This would make interpretation of my code much easier for me and perhaps others.
I wonder if there's anyone who uses such an extension in visual studio 2015, if so, please explain how to get this working.

Comment: You want to display the image in the editor itself?

Comment: Yes that's exactly my intention.

Comment: There is a plugin for the 2010 version that does exactly this, but I think you will struggle to find anything similar for the 2015 version.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageComments](https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments) extension allows images to be displayed among code and there is a [workaround](https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments/issues/23) to make it work in VS 2015.

Comment: how to make it in vs2017?

Comment: @lindexi For VS 2017 support, please see the following fork https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MsBishop.ImageComments

Comment: I have hitted some issues with the usage: * image file left locked after the comment has removed or changed; * inserted images has to be scaled like `scale="1.11"` because of poor text anti-aliasing in down scaled image; * images could not be lined on a single row; * images could not be hided, for example, through the `#pragma region` to avoid excessive code text expansion